# OutOfMemoryError in Jsoup.connect().get()

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Trying connect to some sites with Jsoup on Android, and it throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception.
Example:

```
Jsoup.connect("http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/grand-theft-auto-iv/guide/").get();
```

What could be done to avoid this problem?

Jsoup 1.7.1

Comment: The whole page in HTML is ~200Kb. Don't think this is so much. Can you post your java memory settings?

Comment: The DVM has 16MB heap size. Not in all devices, but the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

An OutOfMemoryError means that your application is using more memory than is available to it.  (Duh!)

Your options are:

- Increase the amount of memory that the app is allowed to use.
- Decrease the amount of memory that the app does use.  For instance:

  - Don't read and buffer the entire document before parsing it with jsoup.
  - Make sure that you are not keeping too much information in memory from the pages you are crawling.  Either write it to the file system, or "reduce" it on the fly.
  - Profile the app's memory usage to look for leaks and other problems with excessive memory use.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the get method stores everything in memory, hence when you load a large content you get OOME

From what I can see your options are:

1. Load a smaller document, the document you're trying to load seem to be big. Memory is premium especially on handheld devices
2. Preprocess the documents in chunks and process them one at a time so you don't use as much memory
3. Run your program on an environment with bigger memory
4. Figure out if Jsoup can do buffered IO, if not use a different library or write your own. With buffered IO you only read and process chunks of the data at once, so you don't use too much memory space